# QGIS Tile Layers Plugin crashing when adding custom map

Tags: qgis, basemap, tile-layer

I am trying to add a base map to QGIS using the TileLayerPlugin. However, whenever I execute the plugin QGIS crashes. Specifically, I am trying to add this [basemap](http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/) to QGIS.

I created a .tsv file in TextWrangler that reads as follows:

```
Thunderforest   Thunderforest   http://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/pioneer/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

I went to Web >> TileLayerPlugin >> Add Tile Layer and then added the directory with the .tsv file. I select the .tsv file (see screenshot) and click Add. When I do that QGIS crashes. I also tried inserting this code into the tsv file with no success

```
Thunderforest   Thunderforest   https://[abc].tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce this... it would think for a bit, then crash QGIS. (Ubuntu, QGIS 2.14.3, plugin version 0.70)

I was able to get this to work by replacing **`{s}`** with **`a`**, after trying to load some tiles in manually.

This is not ideal, as you want to spread the load over whatever tile servers are available. But it could be that there's a problem with the `{s}` token . I know that's standard in Leaflet, not sure if this plugin handles it. Would need to look at the code...

So use the following as a workaround (double checking that the spaces are indeed tabs)

```
Thunderforest[TAB]copyright statement[TAB]http://a.tile.thunderforest.com/pioneer/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

Here's what it looks like :-

[image]

You could raise an issue on the [plugin's issues page](https://github.com/minorua/TileLayerPlugin/issues) on GitHub to get a more definitive answer.

Comment: That did that trick. Just so I understand better can you explain what purpose "{s}" serves and how replacing it with "a" was able to fix the issue?

Comment: i think there are usually several endpoints.. a.tileserver.com, b.tileserver.com, c.tileserver.com (this site has 3 - a,b and c, which you can confirm by manually crafting urls to download tiles). Leaflet will distribute requests amongst them equally, sort of 'load balancing'. As I say, you probably want to report an issue to see if this plugin has a way to support this. (In fact, looking at QuickMapServices plugin, it seems you can leave off the 'a.' prefix entirely...)